# Как протестировать, какие сообщения посылает eventBus

Tags: java, android, юнит-тесты, junit, eventbus

Метод после асинхронной обработки посылает сообщение об окончании работы через eventBus. Как в тесте дождаться ответа и проверить, какое событие было послано?